# Expectation of a joint conditional variable

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

i am struggling  to solve this integral, which represents the conditional expectation of a joint pdf
The limits are 0 <z < x
This is the background.
1.Consider two random variables X and Z where Z takes positive values only

- the joint pdf f(x,z) is    exp(-x) for 0 < z < x, and 0 if z > x
- the pdf of z is f(z) = exp(-z)

The expectation of the conditional random variable X|z is a function of the conditioning value z, and it reads

$$E\{X|z\} = \int x*f(x|z) $$

I have to find the E{X|z=1}

Below is my starting point. Giving z=1, then am taking 1/e out of the integral, and what i have left would be

$$ \int_{0}^{x} xe^(-x)dx $$

which i am integrating between 0 and infinity.

$$E\{X|z\} =1/e\int_{0}^{x} xe^(-x)$$

So here are my steps (apologies for mistakes, it's my first time here and i am also rusty in calculus)

u = x, v = exp(-x), u'=1

$$E\{X|z\} = 1/e ( x\int_{0}^{x} e^(-x) - \int 1 * \int e^(-x))$$

$$ 1/e ( x\int e^(-x) - \int 1 * - e^(-x))$$

$$ 1/e ( -x*exp(-x)   - exp(-x) )$$

Now i have the issue. How do integrate between 0 and infinity?
if i substitute zero, i am going to have
$$ -1/e $$

for infinity, the whole equation will be zero as i have two exp(-x)
So E{X|z=1}  == 1/e ?

Could anyone advise?
Kind regards

Comment: You are given that joint pdf of $(X,Z)$ is $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=e^{-x}$ for $0<z<x$? And you want $E[X\mid Z=1]$.  So what is $f_X$ and how does that help you to find this expectation? Please refer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264) tutorial for typesetting math.

Comment: my mistake. i misrepresented the left hand side of the equation

Comment: What is '$E\{X|z\} =1/e\int_{0}^{x} xe^(-x)$' ? What are you integrating? What is the variable of integration? Clearly you haven't bothered to improve your post.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. No, it's not that i didnt bother to improve, its' simply that, as i am a noob in this forum,  i made the wrong assumption of expecting all users of this math stack exchange to be familiar with math and statistics. I have now provided the background, hope the question is clearer now

Comment: Question was clear. Your attempt isn't. I had pointed out the problematic expression in your attempt and was trying to get you to answer your own question. Somehow this has only highlighted my unfamiliarity with the subject.